# Get the value from a marker with ":" in its name in a XML file with Python

Tags: python, xml

I need to extract values from a xml file, which is not complex with "get" function. However the marker name is "ext:numericValue" and the ":" seem to be an issue. I do not know how to overpass it.

The line I am interested in the XML file is as follows

```
<dataIndicator ext:numericValue="1.502144031" name="First index">
```

I try to extract the numeric value 1.502144031 (or string value, it does not matter)
with this code :

```
index = criteria.get("name")
if index == "First index":
    first_index = criteria.get("ext:numericValue")
print(first_index)
```

It does not recognize the marker "ext:numericValue" and it results in 
"None" when calling with get function.

Btw, it works with index.

```
print(index)
>>"First index"
```

I do not know how to overpass the ":" issue.

Comment: What XML parsing module are you using?

Comment: The name of the tag is actually "numericValue" and "ext" is a namespace prefix. How are you parsing the whole document?  Depending on the parser, you may need to provide namespace declaration.